# Appllication of Stoke's Theorem in Functional Analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain with Lipschitz boundary. Let $u,v$ be function defined on $H^1(\Omega)$ such that $u=v$ on boundary of $\Omega(\partial \Omega)$. Then can we say this:
$$|u-v|_{H^1(\Omega)}=0$$
My idea is like this:
$$|u-v|_{H^1(\Omega)}^2=\int_{\Omega}(\triangledown (u-v))^2dx=\int_{\partial \Omega}(u-v)^2ds=0$$
where the 2nd last equality holds from Stoke's Theorem.Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: why is $|w|_{H^1(\Omega)} = \int_\Omega \nabla w$? So $|-x|_{H^1(0,1)} < 0$?

Comment: Whats a square of a vector, and how does Stokes apply?

Comment: Got my mistake!

Comment: (2nd comment is about your edit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Let $u=0$ and $v$ be any [smooth nonzero function compactly supported in $\Omega$.](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwim_KTX5rHZAhUFLlAKHSQrDqMQFggtMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBump_function&usg=AOvVaw1irBnOxCfPvSRJO9d6pmgJ) $|u-v|_{H^1} ≥ |v|_{L^2} > 0 $.